# Simple way to draw with double of normal line width

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seem like the naive `line width=2\pgflinewidth` gives four times normal line width. Why is that?

How can I `\draw` with double of normal line width(`\pgflinewidth`) without e.g. making a new length? I would also prefer not to need to use `sqrt(2)` in any way.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\draw (0pt,0pt) -- (10pt,0pt) node[right]{thin}; 
\draw[line width=2\pgflinewidth] (0pt,-5pt) -- (10pt,-5pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};
\newlength\lw
\setlength\lw{\pgflinewidth}
\draw[line width=2\lw] (0pt,-10pt) -- (10pt,-10pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash lw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Three line segments with different line widths]

Comment: Why not just using `thick` (which is twice as thick as `thin`)?

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Because the line width might be something else than `thin` - it might already be `thick`. The purpose for the use of `\pgflinewidth` throughout TikZ is to setup things relative to current line width and not need to set lengths absolutely.

Comment: The `line width` key sets `\pgflinewidth` to its argument (via PGFMath) and adds `\pgfsetlinewidth` to the stack of options (which gets executed right before the drawing). Why I don't know but this is the cause of your doubly doubled line width. I suggest `\tikzset{line width */.style={line width/.expanded={(#1)*\the\pgflinewidth}}}` and then `line width *=2` with your path. (Or just doing this manually if the relation between old and new linewidth is more complex.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: `line width/.expanded={2*\the\pgflinewidth}` works perfectly here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/671358/8650 - thanks. Will you write an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *reasons* the `line width` key does two things:

1. It sets the `\pgflinewidth` to its argument via `\pgfmathsetlength` (locally).
2. It adds `\pgfsetlinewidth{#1}` to the stack of options that get executed when the path is finalized (inside the `;`).

(PGF globalizes `\pgflinewidth` since it is supposed to be only grouped by a `pgfscope` environment and TikZ works around this for every `\path`.)

This is the reason, why setting `line width` dependent on `\pgflinewidth` doubles it twice since it basically does

```
\pgflinewidth = 2 * \pgflinewidth
\pgflinewidth = 2 * \pgflinewidth
```

---

I suggest expanding `\pgflinewidth` to its value before handing it off to `line width`:

```
line width/.expanded = 2 * \the\pgflinewidth
```

If simple factorization of the line width is needed more often I suggest a `line width *` key defined as such:

```
\tikzset{line width */.style={line width/.expanded={(#1)*\the\pgflinewidth}}}
```

that can be used like `line width *=2` without having to deal with the handler and the `\the`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\tikzset{line width */.style={line width/.expanded={(#1)*\the\pgflinewidth}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
\draw (0pt,0pt) -- (10pt,0pt) node[right]{thin}; 
\draw[line width *=2] (0pt,-5pt)
  -- (10pt,-5pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};
\newlength\lw
\setlength\lw{\pgflinewidth}
\draw[line width=2\lw] (0pt,-10pt)
  -- (10pt,-10pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash lw};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This works?! It seems like I got somehow lost in the idea that it is necessary to store the width. Obviously, this is not really the case, but expansion is already enough. Amazing!

Comment: @JasperHabicht It isn't the first time the `.expanded` handler saved the day. It makes sense that TikZ sets the linewidth immediately (so that it is available to be used in coordinates) but why it also adds `\pgfsetlinewidth` to the path options I'm not sure. (We could also fix `line width` key so that it only evaluates `#1` once and forwards its result to the options but I'm not sure what side effects this might have.)

Answer (score 7):

I think you cannot solve this problem completely without storing the current line width beforehand. I don't know at which point in time Ti*k*Z sets the line width, but it seems that you need to store the value of `\pgflinewidth` before you invoke the option `line width`, because this will in turn update the value of `\pgflinewidth`. You could do the following, which is a more Ti*k*Z-like variation of your solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\newlength{\templinewidth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [font=\tiny, store line width/.code={\pgfmathsetlength{\templinewidth}{#1}}]

\draw[store line width={\pgflinewidth}, line width=\templinewidth] 
    (0pt,0pt) -- (10pt,0pt) node[right]{\textbackslash pgflinewidth}; 

\draw[store line width={\pgflinewidth}, line width={2\templinewidth}] 
    (0pt,-5pt) -- (10pt,-5pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you could also make use of to the underlying PGF layer and change the line width directly over there, but this will change the line width globally:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [font=\tiny, multiply line width/.code={\pgfsetlinewidth{#1*\pgflinewidth}}]

\draw (0pt,0pt) -- (10pt,0pt) node[right]{\textbackslash pgflinewidth}; 

\draw[multiply line width={2}] 
    (0pt,-5pt) -- (10pt,-5pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};

\draw (0pt,-10pt) -- (10pt,-10pt) node[right]{still 2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So, you may want to use this refined approach which first stores the current line width in a PGF key and then uses this key to set the actual line width:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\tikzset{
    stored line width/.initial=0pt,
    store current line width/.code={
        \pgfkeys{/tikz/stored line width/.expanded=\the\pgflinewidth},
    },
    multiply line width/.style={
        store current line width,
        line width={#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/stored line width}}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]

\draw (0pt,0pt) -- (10pt,0pt) node[right]{\textbackslash pgflinewidth}; 

\draw[multiply line width={2}] 
    (0pt,-5pt) -- (10pt,-5pt) node[right]{2*\textbackslash pgflinewidth};

\draw (0pt,-10pt) -- (10pt,-10pt) node[right]{\textbackslash pgflinewidth};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Simpler: `store line width/.code={\pgfmathsetlength{\templinewidth}{\pgflinewidth}` simpler: `\draw \pgfextra{\pgfmathsetlength{\lw}{\pgflinewidth}} [line width=2\lw]` simpler: `\draw \pgfextra{\setlength\lw{\pgflinewidth}} [line width=2\lw]` - back to original - all these solutions has in common the need to have a `\newlength` (or overwrite the line width).

Comment: @hpekristiansen Yes, it is basically just a variation of your idea. I added a second approach that probably needs scoping: use `pgfsetlinewidth` to change the line width.

Comment: I suppose `\pgfsetlinewidth{2\pgflinewidth}
\draw ...;
\pgfsetlinewidth{0.5\pgflinewidth}` actually works.